# Type number in text field which adds to link when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've searched around both stackoverflow and the web for answers to my question, but can't find the right solution.

I am trying to create a text field and button, so that a user can enter a number in the text field and when they click the button it takes them to a URL with that number added to the end of the URL.

For example http://www.website.com/trackingid/NUMBERHERE

If the user typed 000000 in the text field and then hit the button the URL navigated would be http://www.website.com/trackingid/000000

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `JavaScript`?

Comment: Python would also be very good for this... Almost any language would work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of addressing this:

- You could use JavaScript's `window.location`
- You could make the button a link and change it's `href`

### Using window.location

Let's assume your html structure looks like this:

```
<form>
    <!-- The field in which the user types the number -->
    <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="Enter number here" />

    <!-- The button -->
    <button onclick="forward();">Send</button>
</form>
```

When you click the button, the `forward()` javascript method gets called. This method looks like this:

```
function forward() {
    // select the input field
    number = document.getElementById("number");
    // forward to the new page
    window.location = "http://www.website.com/trackingid/" + number.value;
}
```

### Changing the link's href

Now the structure looks like this:

```
<form>
    <!-- The field in which the user types the number -->
    <input type="text" oninput="changeLink(this.value);" placeholder="Enter number here" />

    <!-- The button -->
    <a id="buttonLink"><button>Send</button></a>
</form>
```

Notice that the `<a>`-tag is still completely empty except it's id.

The `oninput=` calls the JavaScript function `changeLink();` with it's current value as a parameter whenever something is written or deleted in it.

This function should look like this;

```
function changeLink(value) {
    // select the link
    link = document.getElementById("buttonLink");
    // change it's href
    link.href = "http://www.website.com/trackingid/" + value
}
```

I hope this helps. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You need JavaScript to do this.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="inputId">
<button type="button" id="buttonId">Click me</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('buttonId').addEventListener('click', function() {
     window.location.href = "http://www.website.com/trackingid/" + document.getElementById('inputId').value;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Solved your issue please check my solution**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>nirajpatel.mdl@gmail.com</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="num" name="num">
  <button id="button">Go Url</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    url = "http://www.website.com/trackingid/";
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var num = $("#num").val();

        window.location.replace(url+num);
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```